# Test powershell variable for value

Tags: powershell

If I run something like:

```
$javaInstall = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product |
               Where-Object {$_.Name -Match "Java"}
```

Which returns the following data:

```
IdentifyingNumber : {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180101F0}
Name              : Java 8 Update 101
Vendor            : Oracle Corporation
Version           : 8.0.1010.13
Caption           : Java 8 Update 101

IdentifyingNumber : {4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10}
Name              : Java Auto Updater
Vendor            : Oracle Corporation
Version           : 2.8.101.13
Caption           : Java Auto Updater
```

How can I test the variable `$javaInstall` for any result that was returned?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "test for any result that was returned"? Do you want to check if a particular value was returned? Any value at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$javainstall.<Property> -eq "Desired String"
```

What you're basically looking at here is a hash table. Key/value pairs. It should be easy enough to .check these properties.

Comment: The $javainstall variable is actually an array. The operation you are suggestion acts more like a filter on the property.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed it to. Thank you!